# How to set Thunderbird as default mail client

Tags: active-directory, thunderbird, gpo

I would like to know the possible way to make Thunderbird default mail client in GPO environment.

I have deployed Thunderbird msi, but I would like to pass default configuration, username from userprofile and mail server configuration and so on.

Is that possible to do with Windows server 2008 (Active Directory GPO) or any other means.

Any relevant idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring it as default email client for Windows works with the command
`helper.exe /SetAppDefaultGlobal`

Supplying the server-config could be done with Autoconfiguration, see for example
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration